# keras custom conv2d initialization

Tags: tensorflow, initialization, keras, convolution

I been trying to figure out how to create a custom initialization for Conv2D layers in Keras.

Could any one show an example on how to manually create a "filter" or weights model as the starting point for training. i.e I would like to pass in a 2d matrix with weights, that can be used as a starting point, to the Conv2D layer.

The matrix could be a gaussian blur filter or a sharpinging filter or edge detector etc.

Answer (score 2):

From Keras documentation on [custom initializers](https://keras.io/initializers/):

```
from keras import backend as K

def my_init(shape, dtype=None):
    return K.random_normal(shape, dtype=dtype)    

model.add(Dense(64, init=my_init))
```

So you can easily define an appropriate, custom initialization in `my_init()` and use that in your `Conv2D` layers.

Comment: How to use a numpy array here instead of the K.random_normal() to initialize ?

Comment: I think you can write `return K.variable(value=val, dtype=dtype)`. The `val` will be a Numpy array of shape = `shape` and type = `dtype`.

Comment: It is initializer not custom filters.